# Next.js API route POST request giving 500 error only on mobile

Tags: typescript, next.js, mobile, axios, prisma

EDIT: After some further testing, I've found that out of multiple mobile devices I've tested, the API request only fails on my personal phone(Which is a Samsung Galaxy Note 20 Ultra, if that makes any difference). I am no longer certain if this is an issue in my codebase or with my device, it makes no sense to me that my personal phone would be the only device that can't make a POST request to my API.

I am having an interesting issue. I am running Next.js with Prisma connecting to my Postgres database, and I have a POST route to add a row to my database connected to a button onClick handler.

This functionality works just fine on both development and production servers, but for some reason when testing production from a mobile device, the server responds with a 500 error. I am certain that the onClick event is firing when the submit button is tapped and the API route is being accessed, but I am stumped as to why this 500 response would only be returned on a mobile device.

Here are some snippets that may be relevant to this issue, though nothing jumps out as off to me:

onClick handler:

```js
const handleAddComment = async ({ content }: commentProps) => {
        if (!session) return;
        let oldState = comments;

        const authorId = session.user.id;
        const postId = issue.id;

        

        try {
            const { data } = await axios.post("../api/comments", { authorId, postId, content });

            const addComments = [
                ...comments,
                {
                    id: data.data.comment.id,
                    authorId,
                    author: data.data.comment.author,
                    postId,
                    content,
                    createdAt: new Date(),
                    updatedAt: new Date(),
                }
            ];
            
            setComments(addComments);
            setCommentContent("");
        } catch(error) {
            console.error(error);
            setComments(oldState);
        }
    }
```

API POST function:

```js
// post

const postComment = catchAsyncErrors(async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    const { authorId, postId, parentId, content } = req.body;
    const comment = await prisma.comment.create({
        data: {
            authorId,
            postId,
            parentId,
            content
        },
        include: {
            author: true,
        }
    });

    res.status(200).json({
        status: "success",
        data: {
            comment
        },
    });
});
```

(catchAsyncErrors is a wrapper function for error handling, it simply adds a catch() to the Promise resolution)

Comment: What does `catchAsyncErrors` *do* with the `catch` data?  Ultimately there should be logging for this.

Comment: Yes, there probably should be, however I'm still fleshing out this project and learning as I go. It currently doesn't do anything with the catch data. Also another interesting thing, the API request works as intended on other mobile devices. I was able to borrow a couple different phones to test on and my personal phone is the only one that gets the 500 response. (I have a Samsung Note 20 Ultra, which, when emulated from browser dev tools, also works as intended, for what it's worth)

Comment: It's very likely that the catch data may tell you something - bad input, missing parameter, etc.  I can't explain why it's just one phone but logging is super important to "catch" these kinds of things.